# Stationarity of Moving Average processes

Tags: time-series, self-study

Consider the infinite order MA process defined by
$$y_t=\epsilon_t+a(\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t-2}+...),$$
where $a$ is a constant and the $\epsilon_t$s are i.i.d. $N(0,v)$ random variable.

What is the best way to show that $y_t$ is nonstationary?  I know that I need to look at the characteristic roots of the characteristics polynomial and then judge whether or not they are outside of the unit circle, but what is the best way to approach this problem?  Should I try rewriting the infinite order MA process as a finite order AR process or is it easier to work the MA process?

Comment: Consider any $t < \infty$. Is $\text{Var}(y_{t+1}) = \text{Var}(y_t)$?

Comment: Awesome!  That makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with infinite series of random variables it helps to know when they actually exist. One simple result dealing with the stationarity is the following. The series $\sum \psi_j X_{t-j}$ converges absolutely, almost surely and in mean if $\sum |\psi_j|<\infty$ and $\sup_tE|X_t|<\infty$. In particular if $X_t$ is stationary so is $\sum \psi_jX_{t-j}$.

In your case $\sum |\psi_j|=1+a+a+...$, so the series does not converge and the sum is not defined.

A more general result about existence of the series of the sum is the following. For any collection of random variables $X_t$, if $\sum E|X_t|<\infty$ then $\sum X_t$ converges almost surely, i.e. is defined. Again in your case this condition is violated since $E|X_t|=aE|N(0,1)|$ and the resulting series are not summable.